# positioning a node relative to multiple nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I would like to place a node relative to multiple nodes. In this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82124/positioning-a-child-node-between-two-parents), the `calc` library is suggested in one of the answers. In the below picture, the centered node (E) is not placed in the exact center of all nodes.

[image]

I can solve this problem by determining the exact position of each node but I would like to take advantage of `positioning` package to carry it out automatically. Is there a way to position a node relative to multiple nodes automatically? (i.e. I mean like `below=of right=of ... etc`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, backgrounds, positioning,fit,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
                      inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \node[place] (A)               {A};
     \node[place] (B) [right=of A]  {B};
     \node[place] (C) [below=of B]  {C};
     \node[place] (D) [left=of  C]  {D};
     \coordinate (Middle) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
     \node[place] (E) [below of=Middle] {E};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `baricentric cs` for such jobs. For details, see the `pgfmanual`, page 133, section 13.2.2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, backgrounds, positioning,fit,petri}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
                      inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \node[place] (A)               {A};
     \node[place] (B) [right=of A]  {B};
     \node[place] (C) [below=of B]  {C};
     \node[place] (D) [left=of  C]  {D};
     \coordinate (Middle) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
     \node[place] (E)  at (barycentric cs:A=0.5,B=0.5,C=0.5,D=0.5)  {E};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust those `0.5` to alter the position.

Answer (score 5):

The barycentric coordinate system in [Harish's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264487/3954) provides a fairly general method; in this concrete case, however you can use the `calc` library (already loaded in your code) simply say

```
\node[place] (E) at ( $ (A)!0.5!(C) $ ) {E};
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}
]
\node[place] (A) {A};
\node[place] (B) [right=of A] {B};
\node[place] (C) [below=of B] {C};
\node[place] (D) [left=of  C] {D};
\node[place] (E) at ( $ (A)!0.5!(C) $ ) {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `\path (A) -- node[place] (E) {E} (C);` which doesn't use `calc` library.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thank you for the answer. Even though this solves the problem but it doesn't address positioning a node relative to multiple nodes. I feel Harish Kumar's answer addresses this issue by considering all the nodes. Upvoted though, Cheers